# Class#price call on ruby instance method

Tags: ruby, oop, object

```
class Ticket
  def price
      1
  end
end
```

I get that i can use a

```
t = Ticket.new
t.price
```

but what Ticket#price do ??
it refers to the instance method price in ticket, but i don't get what is the purpose of this kind of command

some props on examples?

Comment: `Ticket#price` is just how you refer to methods in the Ruby documentation. `#` denotes an instance method whereas `.` or `::` are used for class methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [*@Michael Kohl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454723/classprice-call-on-ruby-instance-method#comment32375718_21454723) told, is right.

> `Ticket#price` is just how you refer to methods in the Ruby documentation. `#` denotes an *instance method* whereas `.` or `::` are used for *class methods*.

Here is a visual representation of the above lines using [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-method) :

```
class Ticket
  def price
      1
  end
  def self.bar;end
end

t = Ticket.new
t.method(:price) # => #<Method: Ticket#price>
                                      ^
Ticket.method(:bar) # => #<Method: Ticket.bar>
                                         ^
```